# Draw Dotted circle on Google Maps using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am new to google maps api I don't know how to create dotted circle on google maps. I have created circle on google maps using the following code

```
circle = new google.maps.Circle({
strokeColor: Settings.CircleRadius.strokeColor, 
strokeOpacity: Settings.CircleRadius.strokeOpacity,
strokeWeight: Settings.CircleRadius.strokeWeight,
fillColor: #0000FF,
fillOpacity: Settings.CircleRadius.fillOpacity,
center: click_latlon, 
map: map,
//clickable: true,
radius: radius_m   //Radius in meters 
});
```

Can someone help me how to draw dotted circle on google maps.

Comment: [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/33prhsjp/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code for the dotted polyline, You can have a try for something similar for a circle

```
 // Define a symbol using SVG path notation, with an opacity of 1.
    var lineSymbol = {
      path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      scale: 4
    };

    // Create the polyline, passing the symbol in the 'icons' property.
    // Give the line an opacity of 0.
    // Repeat the symbol at intervals of 20 pixels to create the dashed effect.
    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [{lat: 22.291, lng: 153.027}, {lat: 18.291, lng: 153.027}],
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      icons: [{
        icon: lineSymbol,
        offset: '0',
        repeat: '20px'
      }],
      map: map
    });
```